# Pulsar: Failure reason while sending message in DLQ

Tags: apache-pulsar

We are using apache-pulsar's retry topic and dead letter topic to handle failures in event processing. In case of a failure in processing, event is retried 3 times via retry topic and if it still fails then message is added in DLQ topic.

Is there a way to add failure message in event while adding that in DLQ after 3 failures?

Example:

```
Event:
{
  "messageId": "message-1234",
  "data": {...}
}
```

I want this event to have error field if it goes in DLQ topic after all retries are exhausted. This will help in understanding the reason of failure while analyzing the DLQ.

Event in DLQ:

```
{
  "messageId": "message-1234",
  "data": {...},
  "errorReason": "Error reason from exception"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the reconsumeLaterAsync(), you can pass the properties which is a customized key-value pair list. The properties will be copied to the message that sends to DLQ. Version 2.10.0 is required.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/pull/13461/files#diff-7154b6670027161a584e42ab7c66bf81ccf5b2f7633286b30dcdef98782764c3R220-R221) is an example.

Comment: I don't think properties are copied to the DLQ. I can see my customised property passed in RLQ and in all retry my custom property was there. But when message was passed to DLQ, it lost properties that i added

Comment: Map<String, String> properties = Collections.singletonMap("prop-1", "val-1");
consumer.reconsumeLaterAsync(message, properties, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

This is how I was adding properties. From DLQ consumer, I was not able to get "prop-1" property

Comment: In DLQ, there are only two properties:
"ORIGIN_MESSAGE_IDY_TIME" -> "120758:0:0:0"
"REAL_TOPIC" -> "persistent://<TENANT>/<NAMESPACE>/<TOPIC>"

Comment: I have added a test [here](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/pull/17217), it worked as expected on the master branch. Which version are you using?

Comment: I think there was some issue with my topic configurations. Message properties are passed to the DLQ topic after failures with version 2.10.0. Thanks :)